# Pygsheets: Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pygsheets

I am new to python and was trying my hand at something. I am trying to load a google sheet using python and for that I'm using pygsheets.

But whenever I try to load a sheet into a dataframe of Pandas, it's throwing an error: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

I tried googling many things. It said that this is mostly due to out of memory (RAM) error. But haven't found a way to resolve this.

```
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file = 'config file name') 
    work_sheet = gc.open('google_sheet_name')
sheet=work_sheet.worksheet_by_title(service)
    all_records = sheet.get_all_records() // this works fine. when I print all_records, I get the desired result.
df = sheet.get_as_df() // throws Segmentation fault.
```

Comment: How big is the sheet? Did you try with a smaller sheet?

Comment: are there other non-columnar data like averages or pivot tables in the sheet, if so remove them?

Comment: @nithin Sheet is not that big. 320 rows 11 columns.

Comment: @Raveen No, there's just text data.

Comment: please show the exact error message you are getting

Comment: also try running get_all_values on the sheet

Comment: @nithin Already have tried get_all_records() you want me to try get_all_values as well?
Also, the error message is: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
Just this line!

Comment: no, get_all_records call get_call values. Was it working?

Comment: @nithin yes, get_all_values() is working.!!

Comment: then do df = pd.DataFrame(values) where values is the output of get_all_values

Comment: sheet.get_all_values() now crashes!

Comment: i think only thing left to do is try in a small sheet (with with a single row and column). you can resize the sheet from pygsheets itself

Comment: @nithin Okay, I'll try that then...

Comment: @nithin Tried using a file with 2 lines. Shows the same error :(

Comment: are you using normal python? or cython or something?

Comment: make sure to set `include_tailing_empty` and `include_tailing_empty_rows` to False on `get_all_values `